# Iterate over files with increasing but non-contiguous number range in the name

Tags: bash, shell-script

The filename contains a pattern of the form `00035023030` which only changes from `...30` to `...35` in the last two digits. But if one number is missed form `30` to `35` like say `31`, it throws the error. How to bypass this error and run the below list of command in loop?

Here `barycorr` is the program which asks me three inputs:

1. `/home/dinesh/Test/output00035023030/sw00035023030xwtw2po_cl.evt`
2. `/home/dinesh/Test/output00035023030/sw00035023030xwtw2po_cl_bary.evt`
3. `/home/dinesh/Test/00035023032/auxil/sw00035023032sao.fits.gz`

The script file I have created for each to run:

```
echo -e "/home/dinesh/Test/output00035023030/sw00035023030xwtw2po_cl.evt
/home/dinesh/Test/output00035023030/sw00035023030xwtw2po_cl_bary.evt
/home/dinesh/Test/00035023030/auxil/sw00035023030sao.fits.gz" | barycorr ra=253.467570 dec=39.760169 &>log

echo -e "/home/dinesh/Test/output00035023031/sw00035023031xwtw2po_cl.evt
/home/dinesh/Test/output00035023031/sw00035023031xwtw2po_cl_bary.evt
/home/dinesh/Test/00035023031/auxil/sw00035023031sao.fits.gz" | barycorr ra=253.467570 dec=39.760169 &>log

echo -e "/home/dinesh/Test/output00035023032/sw00035023032xwtw2po_cl.evt
/home/dinesh/Test/output00035023032/sw00035023032xwtw2po_cl_bary.evt
/home/dinesh/Test/00035023032/auxil/sw00035023032sao.fits.gz" | barycorr ra=253.467570 dec=39.760169 &>log

echo -e "/home/dinesh/Test/output00035023033/sw00035023033xwtw2po_cl.evt
/home/dinesh/Test/output00035023032/sw00035023033xwtw2po_cl_bary.evt
/home/dinesh/Test/00035023032/auxil/sw00035023032sao.fits.gz" | barycorr ra=253.467570 dec=39.760169 &>log
```

Comment: The 30...35 part changes in five places on each line?

Comment: In avobe list first ..30 containing part executes then ...31 and so on. If 31 containing file is not there to give input then program shows error. Need to by pass this error caused.

Comment: What do you mean "by pass"? Do you want to redirect the error message, so it is not printed?

Comment: @Panki I assume what is meant is "skip", so that the `barycorr` command doesn't complain about a non-existing file. But OP should edit the post to clarify.

Comment: @AdminBee thank you for the edit. 'skip' here means while iterating from 30 to 35 if there no 31 then my program stops to run. So I need my program to continue despite of that error.

Comment: Yes, @Panki you are correct.

Comment: How do you run this? With the code you show, if one of the files is missing, you will get an error and then move on to the next file. Sure, you could make it more elegant, but this should still work. Are you sure you have an issue?

Comment: @terdon I run this through commandline making bash script. Yes it work in this way. But if `barycorr` program doesn't find the file lets say ...31.. then it throws error and program stops. So I want to run the program by skiping the error. Is there any method in above command to skip error?

Comment: But this will not stop. Not unless you have `set -e` in your script.

Comment: Is there something missing from the script in the OP that you are not showing?

Comment: .. for example, putting `-e` in the shebang, or set `-e` in the script, will exit completely on the first non-zero command status. Also, DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself. There are far better ways than cut/paste to achieve this. Specifically, the fourth group appears to have "32" instead of "33" in three separate places -- a typical cut/paste fault. A loop over `{30..35}`, and some declarations for many fragments of the filenames, would help a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Your script will not stop and will run all commands. All you need to do is ignore the error. However, you can indeed make it so that it skips missing files. For example, you could rewrite your script like this
(assuming bash release 4 or newer, for the zero-padding in the brace expansion):

```
#!/bin/bash

for num in {00035023030..00035023033}; do
    dir=/home/dinesh/Test/output"${num}"
    file1="$dir/sw${num}xwtw2po_cl.evt"
    file2="$dir/sw${num}xwtw2po_cl_bary.evt"
    file3="/home/dinesh/Test/$num/auxil/sw${num}sao.fits.gz"

    if [[ -e "$file1" && -e "$file2" && -e "$file3" ]]; then
        printf '%s %s %s' "$file1" "$file2" "$file3" | 
            barycorr ra=253.467570 dec=39.760169 &>>log
    else
        echo "Some files missing for $num" >> log
    fi
done
```

#### Explanation

- `for num in {00035023030..00035023033}; do`: the `{start..end}` notation is called "brace expansion" and will expand to all numbers from `start` to `end`:

  ```
  $ echo {00035023030..00035023033}
  00035023030 00035023031 00035023032 00035023033
  ```

The `for variable in something` is a for loop and it will set the value of the variable (`$num`, in this case) to each of the "somethings". This means that this loop will iterate over the numbers from 00035023030 to 0035023033.

- Inside the loop, we simply set up some variables to avoid needing to write very long names and keep everything clean. So we have:

  ```
   dir=/home/dinesh/Test/output"${num}"
   file1="$dir/sw${num}xwtw2po_cl.evt"
   file2="$dir/sw${num}xwtw2po_cl_bary.evt"
   file3="/home/dinesh/Test/$num/auxil/sw${num}sao.fits.gz"
  ```

  `${num}` is needed so that the shell can understand things like `sw${num}xwtw2po_cl_bary.evt` because with `sw$numxwtw2po_cl_bary.evt` the shell would have no way of knowing that the variable's name is `$num` and not `$numxwtw2po_cl_bary.evt`.
- `if [[ -e "$file1" && -e "$file2" && -e "$file3" ]]; then`: this `if` simply checks if all three files exist. The `-e` is checking for file existence. So the `if` will only succeed if all three files are present.

Comment: The third filename in each group does not contain `output` in the `$dir` element (although it probably was intended to -- another cut/paste fault).

Comment: Thank  you but the third input is from different folder. Your script takes all the inputs from same folder. I need to give the third input from this path `/home/dinesh/Test/00035023032/auxil/sw00035023032sao.fits.gz` .

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Yes I need to give input from different path its not copy paste fault.

Comment: @unicorn try the updated answer. It really should be quite simple to fix this sort of thing though: I can only guess what you want to do (your question doesn't tell us), you actually know. So just use the right paths and file names and you should be fine.

Comment: @terdon Thank you very much for your effort . Actually I am novice to bash scripting. It would be great help If you clarify what the commands are doing.

Comment: So you have distinct directories `output00035023032` and `00035023032`, and `output...32` contains a file called `...33...`? This is a catalogue problem, not a script problem. I would probably consider dealing with this using soft links for the stray references. Or maybe keep a text file that cross-references the names, and generates the commands on the fly.

Comment: @unicorn I added an explanation.